# what the difference between RegisterInstance and RegisterType in DI Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I am new in Autofac and i am trying to understand the difference between RegisterInstance and RegisterType in a web api 2 (.Net framework).
Here in his doc have a simple  [example](https://autofac.org/)

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();


// Register individual components
builder.RegisterInstance(new TaskRepository())
       .As<ITaskRepository>();
builder.RegisterType<TaskController>();
builder.Register(c => new LogManager(DateTime.Now))
       .As<ILogger>();

// Scan an assembly for components
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(myAssembly)
       .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
       .AsImplementedInterfaces();

var container = builder.Build();
```

Can someone explain it?

Comment: See: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#instance-components

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RegisterInstance registers a single instance that will be then used as singleton.

RegisterType leaves the creation and lifetime to the container. The default is usually per-request creation.